# Scroll 10 px top to particular div

Tags: javascript, angular

I have written below code to scroll top to particular div and it is working fine.
But I want to scroll 10px more on the particular fields. On click of submit button it is scrolling to the error block, but complete filed is not visible. How do we scroll more to the targeted class.

```
public scrollIntoError(formId: string): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const selector = "#" + formId + " .error-class";
    const firstElementWithError = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.scrollToError(firstElementWithError);
  }, NumberConstants.HUNDRED);
} 

public scrollToError(el: Element): void {
  if (el) {
    el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  }
}
```

Above code is working fine but I want to scroll top 10 px more on the selected class.

**Edit**

Page dosent have any scroll bar only the middle section which has forms has scroll.

Comment: did you look into `alignToTop` or  [scrollIntoViewOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) may be setting something like `block` or `inline` options may give you nearest possible result

Comment: yes @JoelJoseph el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center"});  this worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will scroll smooth in once:

```
public scrollToError(el: Element): void {
    if (el) {
        el.scroll({
            top: el.scrollTop - 10, 
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute one more statement for that:

```
public scrollToError(el: Element): void {
  if (el) {
    el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    el.scrollBy(0, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: most probably `scrollBy` will start working before  `scrollIntoView` completes the scrolling

Comment: I dont have browser scroll, this is a middle section form with a scroll. Main page dosent have scroll. I think window.scroll wont work in this scenario

Comment: Ok, I've edited the comment, it should be el.scollBy, not window.scrollBy